# flex TextLayoutFramework TextScrap how to access the textFlow of a PasteOperation

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, tlf

after reading 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/labs/textlayout/flashx/textLayout/edit/TextScrap.html

flashx.textLayout.edit.**TextScrap** should have a public [read-only] property **textFlow**

but it is protected in flex_sdk_4.1.0.16076...

does anybody know how to access a pasted TextFlow?

Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData("TEXT_LAYOUT_MARKUP") returns only a XML  - not the objects...

Comment: Two different approaches proposed elsewhere on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892707/paste-rich-text-into-flash and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475306/adobe-tlf-with-flex-as3-how-to-programmatically-change-n-in-text-string-into-p

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is being pasted into a RichEditableText component?

If so, you would listen for a [TextOperationEvent.CHANGING](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/TextOperationEvent.html) event which will have a [FlowOperation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/operations/FlowOperation.html) that you can use to reference the TextFlow. You will to check if(FlowOperation is PasteOperation) before doing so. This can also be captured post update by listening for "change", but then you won't be able to manipulate the operation if needed (which I'm assuming is why you need to access the flow object).