# Adobe TLF with Flex/AS3: how to programmatically change \n in text string into paragraph tags and insert into TextFlow?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tlf

My Flex/AS3 web application accesses a database and retrieves text containing \n for newline character. Otherwise the text looks like normal text.

Is there a way to convert the \n into paragraph tags that I can insert into an spark TextFlow?

For example, my only experience with TLF is in writing mxml code such as follows:

```
<s:RichEditableText width="100%" height="100%"
                    textAlign="left" paddingTop="0"
                    paragraphSpaceAfter="0.3"
                    editable="false">
<s:textFlow>
  <s:TextFlow>
    <s:p fontWeight="bold" fontSize="15">My Title Text</s:p>
    <s:p fontSize="2"/>
    <s:p>{paragraph1_text}</s:p>
    <s:p>{paragraph2_text}</s:p>
    <s:p>{paragraph3_text}</s:p>
    <s:p fontSize="2"/>
  </s:TextFlow>
</s:textFlow>
</s:RichEditableText>
```

Suppose I retrieve a string from the database such as:

`paragraph1_text = "This is some text.\nThis is some more text.\nThis is even more text."`

Even though inserting this into the code above will recognize the new line character, it won't recognize the `paragraphSpaceAfter="0.3"`. My goal is to have the effect of:

```
<s:RichEditableText width="100%" height="100%"
                    textAlign="left" paddingTop="0"
                    paragraphSpaceAfter="0.3"
                    editable="false">
<s:textFlow>
  <s:TextFlow>
    <s:p fontWeight="bold" fontSize="15">My Title Text</s:p>
    <s:p fontSize="2"/>
    <s:p>This is some text.</s:p>
    <s:p>This is some more text.</s:p>
    <s:p>This is even more text.</s:p>
    <s:p>{paragraph2_text}</s:p>
    <s:p>{paragraph3_text}</s:p>
  <s:p fontSize="2"/>
</s:TextFlow>
```

Is there any way to achieve something like this programmatically (the database text could be anything)?

I tried changing paragraph1_text to:

`paragraph1_text="<s:p>This is some text.</s:p><s:p>This is some more text.</s:p><s:p>This is even more text.</s:p>"`

and then using this in the first code block above, but it simply printed out all of the `<s:p>` and `</s:p>` tags.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using ActionScript.  Let's say you name your TextFlow like

```
<s:TextFlow id="myFlow">
```

Your ActionScript code block could look like:

```
import flashx.textLayout.elements.*;

public function insertParagraph( textFlow:TextFlow, text:String, locationIndex:uint ):void
{
    var paragraphs:Vector.<ParagraphElement> = getParagraphElements( text );
    for ( var i:uint = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++ )
    {
        textFlow.addChildAt( paragraphs[i], locationIndex + i );
    }
}

public function getParagraphElements( text:String ):Vector.<ParagraphElement>
{
    var textParagraphs:Array = text.split("\n");
    var result:Vector.<ParagraphElement> = new Vector.<ParagraphElement>();
    for ( var i:uint = 0; i < textParagraphs.length; i++ )
    {
        var p:ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
        var span:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
        span.text = textParagraphs[i];
        p.addChild(span);
        result.push(p);
    }

    return result;
}
```

In your case, since you want to add the paragraphs starting as the 3rd element, once the text is retrieved, you can call     insertParagaph( myFlow, text, 2 );

Comment: The line of code: `textFlow.addChildAt( paragraphs[i], locationIndex + i );` should be `textFlow.addChildAt( locationIndex + i, paragraphs[i] );`, but otherwise works perfectly. Thanks so much Tianzhen Lin!